# How to load parasolid (.x_t) file in three js

Tags: three.js

can anyone please suggest how to load parasolid file in three js?
like

```
var loader=New THREE.ObjectLoader();
loader.load('path',callback);
```

is there any loader available for parasolid?

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! Please, read about [ask] and [mcve]. Also, you can ask your question on that [forum](https://discourse.threejs.org/).

Comment: @mrdoob please help me on this

Comment: Please do some research first. The three.js package does not include an x_t loader, and if you were unable to find one through web searches, then it is unlikely one exists (for open use). This leaves creating one yourself, which includes opening and parsing an x_t and translating it into three.js objects. It's not impossible, but it's way beyond the scope of a StackOverflow question.

Answer (score 0):

there is no way, it should be converted to another format like `obj` or `stl`
check [here](https://discourse.threejs.org/t/how-to-load-parasolid-file-in-three-js/2106) and [here](https://discourse.threejs.org/t/can-we-work-in-three-js-with-step-x-t-x-b-how/28512)